# jquery ajax send the request two times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem when I send values ​​to the processing page
Values ​​are sent more than once
I changed to the .on() in jQuery function but the same issue
Some pages run without problems, but update and delete times are repeated

the ajax

```
    /* Start Update User From Moadl Bootstrap   */
$('#EditForm').submit(function(event){
    var that = $(this), 
    url = that.attr('action'), // action to function.php
    type = that.attr('method'), // Method POST default
    data  = {}; 
    event.preventDefault(); // for stop submit action forward 

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
        var that = $(this);
        var name = that.attr('name'); 
        var value = that.val(); // the vaule of ['name']="xxx"
        data[name] = value; // data
        console.log(data);  /* show the data */ 
    });

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:type,
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
        //  console.log(data);
        //  $('div#EditModal button.btn-success').attr('data-dismiss','modal')
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $('div#EditModal').modal('hide'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); // remove black screen
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();//remove black screen
            $('#alert-success').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000); //fadeIn alert
        }
    })
});
/*  End Update User     */
```

the php code

```
function update($db){
    if(isset($_POST['udid_update']) || isset($_POST['phone_update'])){
$name   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['name_update']);
$udid   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['udid_update']);
$phone  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,(int)$_POST['phone_update']);
$email  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email_update']);
$group  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['group_update']);

$query = "UPDATE `$group` SET `num_phone` = '$phone', `udid` = '$udid', `name` = '$name', `email` = '$email' WHERE `$group`.`num_phone` = $phone";

$do = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    /*
if($do)
    echo 'Done'.$query;
else 
echo 'not'.$query;
    return true;*/

    }
}
update($db);
```

Picture of the problem

[image: request post 2 times]

Comment: FYI, you can use `var data = that.serialize()` to get all the form values. See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Also, I highly recommend you use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to perform your query. FYI, you are missing quotes around the last `$phone`. When you use parameter binding, you don't have to worry about such problems

Comment: Are you actually seeing two AJAX requests being made? Your console output doesn't explain the problem at all. Check your *Network* console

Comment: Where is this `$('#EditForm').submit(function(event){})` in respect to your other code? Are you sure this part isn't getting called more than once and thus creating two submit event listeners?

Comment: @PatrickEvans  just tow button to $('#EditForm') form one to delete and another to update ...

Comment: Something is causing the submit handler either (a)  to be attached twice, or (b) to be triggered twice. Either way, the cause is not apparent in the code in the question. You must simply trawl through your code and find the bug. That's programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#EditForm').submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        url:$(this).attr('action'), 
        type:'post', // you can change this to $(this).attr('method')
        data:$(this).serialize(), //This line will serialize all form fields
        success:function(data){ 
            // Here you can do any code to show success message
            $(this)[0].reset(); // This line will reset the form after success
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: The same problem it is request two times .